# Visual Studio Login Page with local SQL server database

Tags: c#, sql, authentication, tableadapter

I'm creating a visual studio project that uses a local SQL server database as a data source, which is up and running correctly.

I need to create a login form for the project.

The form has a username textbox and a password textbox which the user will populate with their details, and then hit the 'login' button, which needs to execute the select sql statement.

Any references on how to do this?

The code I have tried is below. 
It's throwing a NullReferenceException at the line that says "SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();"

How do I Solve the nullreferenceexception?

Thank you!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MARKO-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial     Catalog=IS2B_G8_FundMeDB;Integrated Security=True";
                con.Open();

                String sql = "Select * from APPLICANT where     applicant_ID_passport =@user AND password = @password";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@user", txtUserName.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password",     txtPassword.Text));
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Failed");
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException sqle)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sql Exception");

            }


        }
```

Comment: Similar problem/solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347457/what-is-wrong-with-my-c-sharp-login-code/40348686#40348686).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string struser = txtUserName.Text;
string strpwd = txtPassword.Text;

 String sql = "Select * from APPLICANT where applicant_ID_passport=" + struser + " AND password = " + strpwd +"";
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
             SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some research into using ADO.Net, specifically the SQLCommand class.

However I would refrain from using inline sql statements like above as this opens you up to SQL injection. Rather use paramaterised queries, stored procedures or LINQ to SQL.

Comment: You should definitely do what Christopher has said above. However further from that I would suggest selecting a count from applicant and if it is greater than 0 then they exist.

Comment: Thanks so much guys! I'm editing the question with the code i have done so far. I'm now having another issue which I'll update the question with.

Comment: Have you solved this? I am unsure as to the nullreference you are getting, I have never used the execute reader for data retrieval. I have always just used com.ExecuteNonQuery() for inserts,updates and deletes and for retrieving data I used executeScalar if the query returns a single value. If you are retrieving a dataset I would rather use a SqlDataAdapter and a datatable to get the data.